# price predicting using regreddion

Tags: algorithm, scikit-learn, regression, prediction

I have dataset of gold prices and after modifying and some preprocessing i ended up with dataframe below:[image]

There is 50,000 record in dataset and there are morethan 500 different markets with different frequencies, all columns expect date are int type and date is datetime object. i need to predict price per unit in some specific dates. but somehow i baffled with so many methods.

My question is what regression algorithm/method is results good prediction for this kind of data ?

Comment: this question is far too broad. Market-analysis is a pretty complex topic that involves quite a lot of classification on existent data. And the fact that you apparently plan to implement this in a cross-market scale doesn't make things easier. This topic could fill entire books. Definitely not the format of question that can be answered here. I'd suggest you read up on computational market-analysis on your own and come back with a more specific question

Comment: I recommend to start your explorations with a linear regression on a few randomly selected example markets. If they model well, then scale them to all markets and perhaps investigate inter-market correlations. I would not recommend entering the machine learning arena if you are a newbie with a large dataset like this. There be beasts in there that love unprepared flesh.

Comment: after some searching and exploring web, I just figured out for analysing and predicting **time series** -as this data is, **ARIMA** models work fine if utilise carefully.

Answer (score 1):

In machine learning or data mining as they always say, a lot of things can be done in a lot of ways. Lets try to use elimination to decide on the algorithm for the given problem.The primary case is that the class variable (feature to be predicted) is continuous hence you should use any regression algorithms. I would suggest to go with linear regression, check the accuracy using r^2 score which is basically a squared difference between an actual and a predicted value. If it is not on par, try randomforest regressor.